# Master Page and Child Page concept!

Tags: asp.net, master-pages

I have a aspx web page. if i change something in the page and when it refreshes , does it load just the child page or even the master page?? What function one should use to refresh Master page as well!! I hope i am clear!!! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 0):

The Page_Load of the child page will fire first followed by Page_Load of the masterpage. You may find this slightly counter intuitive. I know I did!

If you are relying on something in your master page being accessible from the code-behind in your child page you should reference it later eg in the Page_PreRender event of the child page.

Master page should always refresh. Not sure what you are experiencing?